# CK13N transaction read text from GuiTree table fields using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I'm looking for a solution how to read text from SAP table.

I can select specific cell in table, but don't know the reference to get its text value.

Below code works fine but what I need is instead of `selectItem` I need to get text from this item.

Relevant part of code :

```
Dim SapGuiAuto, SAP, Connection, Session

If Not IsObject(SAP) Then
    Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
    Set SAP = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
    Set Connection = SAP.Children(0)
    Set Session = Connection.Children(0)
End If

ReDim ArrSap(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
Session.findById("wnd[0]/shellcont[0]/shell/shellcont[1]/shell[0]").pressButton "MATE"
Session.findById("wnd[0]").iconify

On Error Resume Next

For i = 1 To 999
    Select Case i
        Case Is > 99
            Case Is > 99
            Session.findById("wnd[0]/shellcont[0]/shell/shellcont[1]/shell[1]").selectItem "        " & i & "", "C         10"
            Session.findById("wnd[0]/shellcont[0]/shell/shellcont[1]/shell[1]").expandNode "        " & i & ""
        Case Is > 9
            Session.findById("wnd[0]/shellcont[0]/shell/shellcont[1]/shell[1]").selectItem "         " & i & "", "C         10"
            Session.findById("wnd[0]/shellcont[0]/shell/shellcont[1]/shell[1]").expandNode "         " & i & ""
        Case Else
            Session.findById("wnd[0]/shellcont[0]/shell/shellcont[1]/shell[1]").selectItem "          " & i & "", "C         10"
            Session.findById("wnd[0]/shellcont[0]/shell/shellcont[1]/shell[1]").expandNode "          " & i & ""
    End Select
Next i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A faster solution might look like this:

```
...
set myTree = Session.findById("wnd[0]/shellcont[0]/shell/shellcont[1]/shell[1]") 
For i = 1 To 999
 myTree.selectItem right(space(10) & cstr(i),11) , "C         10"
 myTree.expandNode right(space(10) & cstr(i),11)
 myText = myTree.getItemText (right(space(10) & cstr(i),11) , "C         10")
 msgbox myText
Next i
```

Regards,
ScriptMan

Answer (score 1):

I know a workaround.

for example:

```
...
For i = 1 To 999
 Session.findById("wnd[0]/shellcont[0]/shell/shellcont[1]/shell[1]").selectItem right(space(10) & cstr(i),11) , "C         10"
 Session.findById("wnd[0]/shellcont[0]/shell/shellcont[1]/shell[1]").expandNode right(space(10) & cstr(i),11)
 session.findById("wnd[0]/shellcont[0]/shell/shellcont[1]/shell[1]").itemContextMenu right(space(10) & cstr(i),11) , "C         10"
 session.findById("wnd[0]/shellcont[0]/shell/shellcont[1]/shell[1]").selectContextMenuItem "&FIND"
 myText = session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/txtLVC_S_SEA-STRING").text
 session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[12]").press
 msgbox myText
Next i
```

Regards,
ScriptMan

Comment: Tried it but it's really slow and i have thousands of rows to check. Thx. I'll probobly solve this by another transaction if i get my hands on it.